# Whats wrong with this jtextarea

Tags: jcombobox, jtextarea

I have a database called staff and table called leavereq.

The table looks like this

```
id    reason                   status 
j201  some reason              yes 
j203  some valid reason 2      no
```

I have successfully displayed id's in JCombobox. Now I want to display the value of reason attribute into jtextArea such that it should be correspond to the id selected from the combobox.

If j201 id is selected from combo box, then the reason bolongs to it(some reason) should display inside textarea.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
try
                            {
                              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/staff?"+"user=root&password=letmein");
                             PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn1.prepareStatement("Select * from leavereq");

                             ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();


                             while(rs1.next())
                             {
                            leave.addItem(rs1.getString("id"));                         
                             }                          
                                 String selectedItem = (String)leave.getSelectedItem();
                            PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn1.prepareStatement("Select * from leavereq where id=?");
                            stmt2.setString(1,selectedItem);
                            ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();                           
                            jta2.setText(rs2.getString("reason"));
                        }
                         catch (Exception ex)
                         {
                              System.out.println(ex);
                         }
```

Why cant I get the contents inside jTextArea?